# Trying to draw using DrawingContext,but when I try calling Close(), a StackOverflowException occurs

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, system.windows.media

I'm trying to draw ~150 GeometryDrawing objects on a Canvas.

I do this by adding them to a DrawingGroup. I `Open()` the Drawing group, add the GeometryDrawings, draw the group with the `DrawingContext` and then `Close()` the `DrawingContext`. I add the result to a `Image.Source` and add this to the canvas.

On closing, my App throws a `System.StackOverflowException` and I can't seem to find out why?

```
    internal void Draw(List<GameObject> gameObjects, List<Ray> lighting)
    {
        DrawingGroup group = new DrawingGroup();
        List<GeometryDrawing> geometries = new List<GeometryDrawing>();
        geometries.AddRange(Draw(gameObjects));
        geometries.AddRange(Draw(lighting));

        DrawingContext dc = group.Open();
        foreach (GeometryDrawing g in geometries)
        {
            group.Children.Add(g);
        }
        dc.DrawDrawing(group);
        dc.Close();

        Image image = new Image();
        image.Width = 800;
        image.Height = 500;
        DrawingImage di = new DrawingImage(group);
        image.Source = di;

        Canvas.SetTop(image, 0);
        Canvas.SetLeft(image, 0);
        canvas.Children.Add(image);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the StackOverflowException is that

```
dc.DrawDrawing(group);
```

adds `group` to its own `Children` collection, resulting in an infinite recursion.

You are mixing the ways to populate the Children of a DrawingGroup. *Either* directly add Drawings to the `Children` collection *or* use a DrawingContext to populate the collection, not both at the same time.

This should work:

```
using (var dc = group.Open())
{
    foreach (var g in geometries)
    {
        dc.DrawDrawing(g);
    }
}
```

Or just don't use a DrawingContext at all:

```
foreach (var g in geometries)
{
    group.Children.Add(g);
}
```

Comment: That fixed the OverflowException. I do think it's strange that there are two ways to go about this. There's probably a reason for this that i'm not seeing. I wonder if this is the most efficient way to draw passive shapes in a canvas.

Comment: DrawingImage should be quite efficient. An alternative might be a DrawingVisual, but I would not expect any significant difference in  performance. In any case, you should call Freeze() on the DrawingGroup when it's not going to be modified later. And of course if all the Drawings use the same Pen and Brush, you could combine them into a single Geometry.